# Samba Shared Folder

Tags: rhel, samba

I want to share a folder on my RHEL to all windows users.

My requirements are:

1. users need to access from windows
2. users need read only access
3. no authentication required

What I have tried:

1. Samba Server is up and running
2. Webmin module installed to use SambaUI
3. Webmin > Servers > Samba Windows File Sharing
4. Created a new file share with path as /home/guest/testfolder
5. Used myshare as share name
6. In security:

   - -Writable :no
   - -Guest access: Guest Only
   - -Guest unix user: nobody
   - -Hosts to allow: all
   - -Hosts to deny: none

I am able to see the folder testfolder but I am not able to browse its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does guest Unix user have access to the underlying Unix folder that you're trying to share?

Permissions can get a little confusing when dealing with Samba. The user's that you specify in the `smb.conf` file need to have access to the Unix filesystem.

So in your case I would assume that the user nobody doesn't have read access to `/home/guest/testfolder`.

#### selinux

As you've discovered SELinux can impact you're ability to access a directory using Samba. You can do a couple of things if SELinux is blocking you:

**- disable it...**

This command will temporarily disable it:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

This is helpful when trying to determine if it's an issue.

**- enable `/home` Samba access for SELinux...**

You need to run this command on the samba server:

```
$ sudo setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs 1.
```

If the directories are under /home.

**- enable `/some/other/dir` Samba access for SELinux**

If they're anywhere else you need to re-tag their SELinux contexts' like so:

```
$ sudo chcon -t samba_share_t /some/other/dir
```

Comment: I tried setting the user to guest but still of no avail. Do I have to do any other configurations ?

Comment: @AnandSunderraman - Can you share your stanza from your `smb.conf` file for this one share?

Comment: hey got it working, turns out that I have to disable SELinux. I will post my findings in an answer

Comment: @AnandSunderraman - good catch. I always forget about it. You can temporarily disable it `setenforce 0`. You need to run this command on the samba server `setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs 1`. If the directories are under `/home`. If they're anywhere else you need to retag their selinux contexts' like so: `chcon -t samba_share_t /var/eng`.

Comment: @AnandSunderraman - see updates.